# How can i get many values with single key of json laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, laravel

Hi i want to ask how to send json in array instead send them one by one. 
i am using laravel and vue.js
i am new in laravel and i want to know better
i tried to looping but it failed

here the example:

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "activity_id": 1,
                "start_date": "2018-11-06",
                "product_name": "ks",
                "topic_name": "exploration"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "subproduct_name": "bcd"
            },
            {
                "subproduct_name": "cfr"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

i want to get them like this

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            {
                "activity_id": 1,
                "start_date": "2018-11-06",
                "product_name": "ks",
                "topic_name": "exploration",
                "subproduct_name":["bcd","cfr"]
            }
        ],

    ]
}
```

and this is my controller

```
 public function getActivity()
{



    $getData = DB::table('new__businesses')->select('new__businesses.activity_id','new__businesses.start_date','new__businesses.end_date','new__businesses.corporate_name','ms__subsidiaries.subsidiary_name','ms__products.product_name','ms__topics.topic_name')
    ->leftjoin('ms__subsidiaries','ms__subsidiaries.subsidiary_id','=','new__businesses.subsidiary_id')
    ->join('ms__products','ms__products.product_id','=','new__businesses.product_id')
    ->join('ms__topics','ms__topics.topic_id','=','new__businesses.topic_id')
    ->get();

    $getSubproduct = DB::table('new__businesses')
        ->select('ms__subproducts.subproduct_name')
        ->join('store__subproducts','store__subproducts.activity_id','=','new__businesses.activity_id')
        ->join('ms__subproducts','ms__subproducts.subproduct_id','=','store__subproducts.subproduct_id')
        ->get();

    $getPic = DB::table('new__businesses')
        ->select('ms__users.user_name')
        ->join('pics','pics.activity_id','=','new__businesses.activity_id')
        ->join('ms__users','ms__users.user_id','=','pics.user_id')
        ->get();

        return response()->json([
            'data'=>$getData,
            'pic'=>$getPic,
            'subproduct'=>$getSubproduct
        ]);        


}
```

}

please give me the solution, i am stucked

Comment: You can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#retrieving-results) instead of `get` for your subproducts, so it will just return a single array of column values, instead an array of objects.

Comment: Thank you. problem solve :)))))

Comment: @aynber Add as answer so it can be marked as correct

Answer (score 0):

If you use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#retrieving-results) instead of `get`, you'll get a single array of values instead an array of objects, that you can then add to your array.

```
$getSubproduct = DB::table('new__businesses')
    ->join('store__subproducts','store__subproducts.activity_id','=','new__businesses.activity_id')
    ->join('ms__subproducts','ms__subproducts.subproduct_id','=','store__subproducts.subproduct_id')
    ->pluck('ms__subproducts.subproduct_name');
```